# How to replace Java Semaphore's acquire and release with Java monitors synchronized, wait and notify(All)

Tags: java, multithreading, monitors

My code works with semaphores, but I want to make this work with Java monitors: wait, notify, notifyAll and synchronized instead of acquire and release. Can anyone tell me how I can do this?

```
public class Track {

    private final Semaphore mutex = new Semaphore(1,true);
    private final Semaphore use = new Semaphore(1,true);

    public Track(){}

    public void gebruikWissel(String v) throws InterruptedException
    {
        mutex.acquire();
        System.out.format("Trein %s maakt gebruik van de wissel", v);
        mutex.release();
    }

    public void useTrack() throws InterruptedException
    {
        use.acquire();
    }

    public void stopUseTrack()
    {
        use.release();
    }
}
```

Comment: Haha, jag visste det när jag såg rubriken. Hej Emil!

Answer (score 3):

you can do it using synchronized and a simple internal counter, e.g.:

```
private int counter;

public synchronized void useTrack() throws InterruptedException
{
    while(counter == 1) {
      wait();
    }
    counter++;
}

public synchronized void stopUseTrack()
{
    counter--;
    notifyAll();
}
```

UPDATE:
didn't realize this was homework.  well, i hope i get a good grade!

Comment: a downvote?  for what?  the answer is correct.  the "homework" tag was added after i answered.  i could remove my answer, but the cat is already out of the bag at this point?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can the way your class is structured. You can't even write a `useTrack()` or 'stopUseTrack()' method that use synchronization, for example.

It is more common for people to go *from* synchronization *to* semaphores. Why do you think you want to go in the opposite direction.

Comment: Because we have to for school :D

Comment: @user735646 - you should add the 'homework' tag and try to do this yourself first.  Asking experienced developers to do your complete assignment is self-defeating.  Have a go, try it and, if it does not work, try to debug it.  Debugging is so important that it's amazing that so many posts here from experienced devlopers show an apalling lack of skill in this area.  You should get good at it by writing software that does not work, (it's very easy to do this, honest:), and fixing it.